# winsock2 tcp fails to recv on second time running the executable

Tags: c++, tcp, winsock, winsock2

I am working on a cross-platform server and client. The client side is Unity3d app and the client side is written in C++. It works fine in Linux and Mac but not in Windows. So I pressume that I am doing something wrong with Winsock2.

It is quite strange. The first time I compile it, it works fine. When I close the executable and run it again, the server side fails to recv after awhile (after sending/receiving about 5~10 msgs). It just hangs at `recv` function. The checked it with wireshark. The client sent the message. But the server fails to receive. Once this happens, it stops working even after making the connection again.

I am force closing the app. This will probably not close the socket properly. But I don't see a way to close it nicely when the users just shut down the executable.

Here is a reproducible code

```
#include <chrono>
#undef UNICODE
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> receive_buffer;
int client_;
int server_fd;
int port_ = 8080;
bool terminateRequested_ = false;
bool connected_=false;
char tempBuffer[1024];

inline bool processRequests() {
    std::cout<<"recv \n";
    int recv_size = recv(client_, &receive_buffer[0], 1024, 0);
    std::cout<<"recv "<<recv_size<<" \n";
    if (recv_size <= 0) {
        std::cout<<"recv failed \n\n";
        return false;
    }
    tempBuffer[1023] = 'e';

    send(client_, &tempBuffer[0], 1024, 0);
}

inline bool waitForReadEvent(int timeout) {
    fd_set sdset;
    struct timeval tv;

    tv.tv_sec = timeout;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&sdset);
    FD_SET(server_fd, &sdset);
    return select(server_fd + 1, &sdset, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0;
}

inline void loop() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    // holds address info for socket to connect to
    struct addrinfo *ptr = NULL;

    int opt = 1000000000;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    std::string portInString = std::to_string(port_);

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, portInString.c_str(), &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    server_fd =
            socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (server_fd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt));
    setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt));

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(server_fd, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(server_fd);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    iResult = listen(server_fd, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(server_fd);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }


    while (!terminateRequested_) {
        if (waitForReadEvent(2.0)) {
            client_ = accept(server_fd, NULL, NULL);
            connected_ = true;
        }

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point lastChecked, current;
        lastChecked = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        while (connected_) {

            if (processRequests()) {
                lastChecked = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            } else {
                current = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

                if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(current - lastChecked).count() > 3.0) {
                    std::cout<<"The client has been disconnected for "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(current - lastChecked).count()<<" seconds. Waiting for a new connection..."<<std::endl;
                    connected_ = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closesocket(server_fd);
    WSACleanup();
}

int main() {
    receive_buffer.resize(1024);
    std::fill(receive_buffer.begin(), receive_buffer.end(), 0);
    loop();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the wireshark output

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    110 4.532631       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      56     9910 → 8080 [PSH, ACK] Seq=133 Ack=455184963 Win=2609408 Len=12

Frame 110: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9910, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 133, Ack: 455184963, Len: 12

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    111 4.532650       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      44     8080 → 9910 [ACK] Seq=455184963 Ack=145 Win=999997440 Len=0

Frame 111: 44 bytes on wire (352 bits), 44 bytes captured (352 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8080, Dst Port: 9910, Seq: 455184963, Ack: 145, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    112 4.532856       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      1068   8080 → 9910 [PSH, ACK] Seq=455184963 Ack=145 Win=999997440 Len=1024

Frame 112: 1068 bytes on wire (8544 bits), 1068 bytes captured (8544 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8080, Dst Port: 9910, Seq: 455184963, Ack: 145, Len: 1024

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    113 4.532873       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      44     9910 → 8080 [ACK] Seq=145 Ack=455185987 Win=2608384 Len=0

Frame 113: 44 bytes on wire (352 bits), 44 bytes captured (352 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9910, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 145, Ack: 455185987, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    114 4.540624       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      56     [TCP Retransmission] 9912 → 8080 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 114: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9912, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    115 4.540673       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      56     [TCP Port numbers reused] 8080 → 9912 [SYN, ACK] Seq=810974615 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=16384 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 115: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8080, Dst Port: 9912, Seq: 810974615, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    116 4.540693       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      44     9912 → 8080 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=810974616 Win=327424 Len=0

Frame 116: 44 bytes on wire (352 bits), 44 bytes captured (352 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9912, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 1, Ack: 810974616, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    117 4.546600       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      56     9912 → 8080 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=810974616 Win=327424 Len=12

Frame 117: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9912, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 1, Ack: 810974616, Len: 12

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    118 4.546614       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      44     8080 → 9912 [ACK] Seq=810974616 Ack=13 Win=999997440 Len=0

Frame 118: 44 bytes on wire (352 bits), 44 bytes captured (352 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8080, Dst Port: 9912, Seq: 810974616, Ack: 13, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    119 4.665321       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      56     [TCP Retransmission] 9909 → 8080 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 119: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9909, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    120 4.665382       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      56     [TCP Port numbers reused] 8080 → 9909 [SYN, ACK] Seq=2078265275 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=16384 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 120: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8080, Dst Port: 9909, Seq: 2078265275, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    121 4.665401       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      44     9909 → 8080 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2078265276 Win=327424 Len=0

Frame 121: 44 bytes on wire (352 bits), 44 bytes captured (352 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9909, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 1, Ack: 2078265276, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    122 6.055260       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      44     9909 → 8080 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2078265276 Win=327424 Len=0

Frame 122: 44 bytes on wire (352 bits), 44 bytes captured (352 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9909, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 1, Ack: 2078265276, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    123 6.055277       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      44     8080 → 9909 [ACK] Seq=2078265276 Ack=2 Win=999997440 Len=0

Frame 123: 44 bytes on wire (352 bits), 44 bytes captured (352 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8080, Dst Port: 9909, Seq: 2078265276, Ack: 2, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    124 6.420665       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      56     9915 → 8080 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 124: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9915, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    125 6.420705       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      56     8080 → 9915 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=65495 WS=16384 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 125: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8080, Dst Port: 9915, Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    126 6.420724       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      44     9915 → 8080 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2619648 Len=0

Frame 126: 44 bytes on wire (352 bits), 44 bytes captured (352 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9915, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    127 6.445091       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      56     9915 → 8080 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=2619648 Len=12

Frame 127: 56 bytes on wire (448 bits), 56 bytes captured (448 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9915, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 12

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    128 6.445109       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      44     8080 → 9915 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=13 Win=999997440 Len=0

Frame 128: 44 bytes on wire (352 bits), 44 bytes captured (352 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 8080, Dst Port: 9915, Seq: 1, Ack: 13, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    129 7.948501       127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      44     9915 → 8080 [FIN, ACK] Seq=13 Ack=1 Win=2619648 Len=0

Frame 129: 44 bytes on wire (352 bits), 44 bytes captured (352 bits) on interface \Device\NPF_Loopback, id 0
Null/Loopback
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 9915, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 13, Ack: 1, Len: 0
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] within the question without relying on external links

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler

Comment: "*I am force closing the app. This will probably not close the socket properly*" - yes, it will. Like any other type of open kernel handle, Windows will close the socket when the process terminates. If `recv()` is hanging, then either you are not sending what it is expecting, or the connection has been unexpectedly lost.

Comment: From Wireshark, c++ side is sending ACK. but the executable hangs at ``recv`` (checking this with two couts before and after). Is this possible?

Comment: @ultrafrog please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem in action, and the Wireshark log at the time the problem occurs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I maded the reproducible code. I left some error checking there in case it might help.

Comment: That server can handle only one client at a time. Consequently if recv, send or closesocket are delayed, the server is blocked. Which is exacerbated by the absence of send/recv timeouts. Anyway, run it under a debugger and click on "pause" when the hang happens. Then look at the stack traces.

Comment: @rustyx The stack traces of WS2? I only have a release version. I cannot find a debug version in system32. I tested this in 5 different windows machines. it works on 4 of them. I have the issue on only one of them...

Comment: Not ws2, your program. See where it's at when a hang occurs.

Comment: I posted the minimal code above. I can see the stack traces without running it...

Comment: @ultrafrog In your server code, `processRequests()` is missing a `return true` statement if `recv()` succeeds. Also, once a client connects and then disconnects, your server is leaking the client socket, as you are not calling `closesocket(client_)` after `recv(client_)` fails. And your whole `lastChecked` timeout logic is useless and should be removed. You are using blocking sockets with no timeouts, so `recv()` will block until data arrives or a disconnect/error happens, so just `closesocket()` immediately, there is no need to wait 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The client was making a new thread and established a connection there. Atfer moving that to the main thread, the issue was gone. I am not sure how this affects the tcp but its working on all my five windows machines now

Comment: How the client is threaded has no affect whatsoever on how the server processes things. Something else has to be going on.